# push commits to my branch in launchpad

Tags: bazaar, launchpad, bzr-svn

I have launchpad repo which I'm pushing commits, and my friend wants to push a patch file into it but when he tried he got this error.

```
$ bzr push :parent
bzr: ERROR: Cannot lock LockDir(chroot-90567632:///~catchsudheera/maria/pcre_regex_enhance/.bzr/branch/lock): Transport operation not possible: readonly transport
```

How would I give him the required permissions? thank you very much.

PS : `bzr info` results:

```
sudheera@Dr-HOUSE-PC:~/Gsoc/mariadb/repo5/maria$ bzr info
Standalone tree (format: 2a)
Location:
  branch root: .

Related branches:
    push branch: bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~catchsudheera/maria/pcre_regex/
  parent branch: bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/maria/
```

Answer (score 1):

Branches starting with address `lp:~catchsudheera` are your private branches on Launchpad. It is not common to let other users push to these branches.

Ask your friend to push to his own Launchpad account, for example `lp:~hisusername/maria/pcre_regex_enhance`. After that, he can visit the page of his branch on Launchpad, `https://code.launchpad.net/~hisusername/maria/pcre_regex_enhance`, and use the **Propose for merging** link to propose the branch for merging into yours. You can then merge his branch in your workspace and push it to your own branch.